# What should $value be when I try to update a B2C Policy using the trustFrameWork API? PUT /trustFramework/policies/{id}/$value

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to update a B2C custom policy I've already POST'd to my B2C tenant.  The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/trustframeworkpolicy-get?view=graph-rest-beta doesn't include any code samples and doesn't really explain what **$value** should be when performing a PUT /trustFramework/policies/{id}/**$value**

Can someone provide some insight as to what $value should be?

Thank you

Comment: Code example - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/custom-policy-manager

Answer (score 1):

For the `PUT` operation, **$value** indicates you are replacing the raw content (i.e. the XML content) of the trust framework policy resource, so it doesn't have to be set to a specific value.

You should only have to set the `Content-Type` request header to `application/xml` and the request body to the XML content of the policy file.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.

Comment: No problems, @Visualjeff, can you please mark the above answer as correct for others to refer to?